# Magento 1.8 Flat table disable after invoice not creating

Tags: magento-1.8, create-invoice, flat

**Issue**: Invoice not created.

Note: Flat tables activated. Problem disappears when Flat tables are disabled.

Comment: you can check on your log files

Comment: clarification: which ones ?

Comment: Exception.log or system.log files